# NoClassDefFound Error when starting WebLogic Server

Tags: java, weblogic, noclassdeffounderror

I am getting a ton of errors when I try to start WLS. I go to the directory /Users/User_JP/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/JP_Domain, and then I enter "sh startWebLogic.sh" and it starts going. (Note: It worked last I tried it, a few days ago...)

And then in the middle I hit:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/bea/logging/BaseLogEntry

 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)

 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)

 at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)

 at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)

 at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)

 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)

 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)

 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)

 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)

 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)

 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)

 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)

 at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)

 at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)

 at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)

 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)

 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)

 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)

 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)

 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)

 at weblogic.logging.MessageLogger.log(MessageLogger.java:62)

 at weblogic.logging.MessageLogger.log(MessageLogger.java:111)

 at weblogic.logging.WLMessageLogger.log(WLMessageLogger.java:52)

 at         weblogic.security.SecurityLogger.logDisallowingCryptoJDefaultJCEVerification(SecurityLogger.java:13444)

 at weblogic.security.utils.SecurityUtils.turnOffCryptoJDefaultJCEVerification(SecurityUtils.java:81)

 at weblogic.Server.main(Server.java:70)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.bea.logging.BaseLogEntry

 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)

 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)

 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)

 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)

 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)

 ... 28 more
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Which version of weblogic are you using? do you have java with your weblogic? for the first time running your weblogic, try running from domain->my_doamin->bin->./startWeblogic.sh &